# Azure Data Factory - Dispose resource timeout

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-data-factory

I try to transfer big SQL data table (~15GB) from local SQL Server on Azure VM to Azure SQL Server with the help of Copy activity and Integrated Runtime. While the small one is completed, the big ones aren't, and fall on timeout with Error Message: "Dispose resource timeout". The full errors are attached. While the SQL server or VM doesn’t has any timeout specified, it still won't work.

The Azure SQL DB is 10 DTUs and Data max size is 250GB.

Copy Activity Timeout: 0.12:00:00
It leaved as default: 12h limitation, but my Copy activity worked until ~2h.

[image]

How can I transfer big amount of SQL table data without timeout limitations and solve this problem?

```
{
    "dataRead": 6427604744,
    "dataWritten": 6427604744,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 2,
    "rowsRead": 20314097,
    "rowsCopied": 20314097,
    "copyDuration": 7630,
    "throughput": 843.296,
    "errors": [
        {
            "Code": 11000,
            "Message": "'Type=System.TimeoutException,Message=Dispose resource timeout,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,'",
            "EventType": 0,
            "Category": 5,
            "Data": {},
            "MsgId": null,
            "ExceptionType": null,
            "Source": null,
            "StackTrace": null,
            "InnerEventInfos": []
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "integrationRuntime1",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "DataMovement",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 2.1333333333333333,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "SqlServer"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "SqlServer"
            },
            "status": "Failed",
            "start": "4/22/2023, 1:40:39 AM",
            "duration": 7630,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 3
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 7622,
                    "details": {
                        "readingFromSource": {
                            "type": "SqlServer",
                            "workingDuration": 161,
                            "timeToFirstByte": 0
                        },
                        "writingToSink": {
                            "type": "SqlServer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 3,
                "timeToFirstByte": 0,
                "transferDuration": 7622
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "NotVerified"
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 3
    }
}
```

[image]

I tried to copy big (!15GB) SQLDB table from local (Azure VM) to Azure SQL Server. It failed and no result.

Comment: Please try using the Bulk insert method for large amount data movement. Enable staging and also try optimizing your query using index.